# How to add checkbox to jquery datatables header?

Tags: jquery, datatables

I would like to add a checkbox or span to a header of datatables table. I don't want to add it in the Html, I want that to do that from javascript at the initialization. Please suggest me.

Comment: What you tried. Show your code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well I did not want to change the html, it's not that a big a change I had to do, just had to add some html at the initialization.

```
    nTable = $('#tblExample').dataTable({
        "bJqueryUI": true,
        "bDestroy":true,
        "bPaginate": false,
        "bSortable": false,
        "aaData":testData,
        "aoColumns": [

                    {   "sTitle": "<input type='checkbox'></input>","mDataProp": null, "sWidth": "20px", "sDefaultContent": "<input type='checkbox' ></input>", "bSortable": false},
                    {   "mDataProp": "Year"},
                    {   "mDataProp": "Month"},
                    {   "mDataProp": "Savings"}

        ]
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<table id="myTable">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>
      <div>
        <input id="checkbox1" type="checkbox"/>
      </div>
    </th>
  </tr>
</thead>
</table>
```

I just now got it your issue. I think this [post](http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/4840/how-to-add-a-checkbox-to-the-table-header/p1) solves this.

Comment: I don't want to change the html as mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 0):

This is old, but I am going to add this statement here for those looking in the future.
 {"mData":"LineItem_nbr",
               "mRender": function (data,type,full) {   data contains the value for the mData
                    return '';
                },
            }

Change LineItem_nbr to the autoID or what ever you are using to identify the record.

This will place a checkbox in the row you add this line, and it is usable looking up by the id, or you can use the class in there for a jQuery grab on multiple items.